# Comparing nucelophlicity order of acetate anion with different nucelophiles

Tags: organic-chemistry

We have hydroxide anion, methoxide anion, bisulfide anion , triphenyl phosphine,  azide anion , 1-pyrrolidine cyclohexene.

We want to tell which of the above species are better nucleophiles than acetate  anion.

We know that good nucleophile  is a weak base, (I know there might be exceptions like cyanide anion), so hydroxide anions, bisulfide anions, methoxide anions are much more basic than acetate ion, so acetate ion should be better nucelophiles than these. However, my question is that whether the rule of  good base   implies a bad nucleophile  will imply here? Also, I'm not sure which criterion do we use to decide for the other three species.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it all of them except the last?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta, it is all of them, how can we compare the last one?

Comment: Dunno what made you think such rule even exists.